How can I resolve `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Record<never, never>'.`
I am trying to get the id off of a route param in Vuejs. I get the error below and cant find a way to solve it.
// how I am accessing the id
const route = useRoute()
const id = route.params.id

Typescript Error:
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Record<never, never> | { all?: string[] | undefined; } | { id: string; } | { id: string; } | { id: string; }'.
  Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Record<never, never>'.ts(2339)

What I have tried:
I have tried using optional chaining and accessing the id as route.params['id'] but cant supress the error.
How can I resolve the issue.

let id = someDefaultValue // in case params doesn't contain id property
if("id" in route.params) id = route.params.id;


Make sure .id is defined in your route table path for that route.
Something like:
path: "/listing/:id"
otherwise the router won't put it in the url and you can't access it that way.
P.S. You should be able to access route directly (no use Route() needed):
this.$route.params.id

as far as I know this.$route is not usable in <script setup> block. useRoute composable must be used in composition API.

useRoute composable accept an optional _name parameter which can be used to infer current route and type properly params.
// if using regular router.js with named route
const route = useRoute("yourRouteNameAsDefinedInRouter");

// may also works with the path if name is not defined on the route (not tested)
const route = useRoute("/path/to/your/file/:id");

// or use file name if using unplugin-vue-router
const route = useRoute("/path/to/your/file.[id]");

// tadam! no longer throw error (and completion works)
const id = route.params.id;

